# How to solve $li(x)$ logarithmic integral for $x > 1$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am trying to write a program in JAVA to find the values of $li(x)$, but I do not understand how to compute $li(x)$ when $x > 1$.

For the sake of this question, let’s make $x = 2$, as this will allow for similarity in the answers.

Any manner of solution is appreciated, however, preferably none of the steps involved in finding the solution can use anything infinite (infinity, infinite summation, infinite series, limits, etc.) as they cannot be expressed in code.

I have included a link to an online calculator for $li(x)$ which also displays the graph:

https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1180573429.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Are you looking for an approximation for large values of $x$ or just for $x>1$ ?

Comment: Just x > 1. In theory, if I can write a program that can solve for x > 1, it should be able to give the value if x is large as well.

Comment: @JackRothenberg - The set of applicable $x$ is important in selecting the best method to approximate $\li(x)$. If you don't care about the computational efficiency then it would be easiest to form a taylor expansion.

Comment: @KevinNivek - I agree that would likely work. The main issue though is that a taylor expansion, to the best of my knowledge, utilizes an infinite series, which is impossible on a computer. Because of this, the answer produced would be inaccurate depending on how far I make the series go. I am however, certainly willing to give this a try. Can you please write the first three or so iterations of the series so I can put it into code? Thank you very much.

Comment: @JackRothenberg - You will never be able to script a program that can find the exact value of a given infinite series (in particular if the resultant value is irrational). As such, you must script an algorithm that converges (as fast as possible) to a defined level of accuracy (i.e. 10, 20, 30, ... decimal places). 

Now, you aren't limited to Taylor Series. Why not employ one of the many computational methods used to approximate integrals? Some examples are given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#Methods_for_one-dimensional_integrals

Comment: @KevinNivek I would also do it with integral approximation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En efficient algorithm, 24-bits precision, can be found in this book : J.Spanier, K.B.Oldham, "An Atlas of Functions", Hemisphere Publishing Co. N-Y., 1987.

Since it is an old edition, a copy of page 355 is shown below.

For $x=2$ the output is $\quad\text{li}(2)\simeq 1.045164$

[image]

More information, from the above referenced document :

[image]

Comment: I am trying to put this into code now. On the 4th line of step one, what is the significance of that number inside the natural log?

Comment: Never mind, I found the value to be equal to exp(gamma).

Comment: Yes, it is $\exp(\gamma)$. A long time ago I implemented the algorithm. I found it satisfactory if 6 or 7 significant digits are sufficient.

Comment: See more information in addition to my main answer.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer, but out of curiosity, how does it work? How do those steps substitute the integral?

Comment: They are a lot of known relationships between the logarithmic integral and series such as whose at the end of my answer. More examples : http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/LogIntegral/

Answer (score 0):

You said you’d consider using a series expansion, so try using $$\operatorname{li}(x)=\gamma+\ln\ln x + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln^k x}{k!\:k}$$

(eq. 14 [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicIntegral.html)) where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: Do you know how to derive that by any chance?

Comment: @KevinNivek hell no lmao